# Set value in each parameter VBA excel

Tags: vba, excel

Example

Column :

```
A       B       C
A001    OK
A002    OK
A003    OK
A004    OK
A004    OK
A004    OK
A004    OK
A004    OK
A004    OK
A004    OK
A004    OK
A004    OK
A004    OK
A004    OK
A004    OK
A004    OK
A004    OK
A004    OK
A004    OK
A004    NO
A004    OK
A004    OK
A004    OK
A004    OK
A006    OK
A007    OK
A008    OK
A010    OK
A010    OK
A015    OK
A015    NO
```

I want to check the value on Column A  and  B.  If Column B has 'OK' value, column C value in that parameter is 'OK'  But  If has only 'NO'  in each on All of copy parameters values are 'NO' in column C. I am using the below code.

```
for i= 1 to 100
    If Cells(i,1).value="A001" and cells(i,2).value="OK" then
        Cells(i,3).value "OK"
    end if
next i
```

But It's not have the value in column C

How should I do this??

Comment: What value should be in column C for the column A value A015? There is one OK and one NO in column B for that one

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using formulas for this. So you can use

```
=IF(AND(A1="A001",B1="OK"),"OK","")
```

And now to answer your question...

1. That may be happening because you are missing an "=" Sign in `Cells(i,3).Value "OK"`
2. That may be happening because the sheet that you want to write to may not be active? And hence you should always qualify your objects. Something like `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Cells(i,1)` So your code becomes

   Code

   ```
   For i = 1 To 100
       With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
           If .Cells(i, 1).Value = "A001" And .Cells(i, 2).Value = "OK" Then
               .Cells(i, 3).Value = "OK"
           End If
       End With
   Next i
   ```
3. If it still doesn't work then maybe there is space in text of Col A and Col B. You may want to then amend the above code to this

   Code

   ```
   For i = 1 To 100
       With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
           If UCase(Trim(.Cells(i, 1).Value)) = "A001" And UCase(Trim(.Cells(i, 2).Value)) = "OK" Then
               .Cells(i, 3).Value = "OK"
           End If
       End With
   Next i
   ```